# PHP OCI Session does not work

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I've been using PHP with oci8 extension. I 'm encountering a problem in implementing sessions. I can't pass the session value through pages. I was able to implement this without oci8 extension. Is there any other way I could implement sessions?

**Log in page** is where I set my session.

```
session_start();        
$_SESSION['id'] = 'ID_1';
header('Location:page.php');
```

**page.php**  should receive the session value.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
{
  header('Location:login.php');
} 
$user = $_SESSION['id'];
echo $user;
```

Comment: It's unlikely `OCI` has anything to do with this. Have you called `session_start()` on `page.php`? If not `$_SESSION` will always be empty.

Comment: I thought it affects the sessions. It works now! Thanks for the help!  @timclutton